# OpenVPN Port 1194 not accepted in iptables policy but still accessible

Tags: iptables, firewall, openvpn

I am able to connect to my OpenVPN server via port 1194, even though this port is not allowed (accepted) in my iptables config. I can confirm no exception is defined as this command gives no output: `iptables -S | grep 1194`

I would expect **not** to be able to connect as my iptables config states a `-P INPUT DROP` policy at the beginning of the file.

It gets even better. Running `nmap -sU -p 1194 localhost` from the host machine gives:

```
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
1194/udp closed openvpn
```

I would expect this port to be open, right? I ran this command at the moment of an open VPN connection.

Also, according to [this article](https://openvpn.net/vpn-server-resources/troubleshooting-access-to-the-web-interface/#:%7E:text=You%20should%20see%20an%20output%20similar%20to%20this%3A), I should see this line:

```
udp    0   0 192.168.70.3:1194   0.0.0.0:*  5713/openvpn-openssl
```

Unfortunately, I don't.

**OpenVPN access server configuration (Admin UI)**
[image: OpenVPN Admin panel]
Only UDP port 1194 has been opened (port forwarded) on the control panel of my internet provider so it can't be the TCP 443 port.

So the final question is:
How is it that I can connect without having to allow this port in my iptables configuration?

Comment: Is your OpenVPN server in any sort of virtual machine or container? There's also a newer firewalling system called `nftables`, so also try `nft list ruleset | grep 1194`

Comment: My OpenVPN server is not installed in a virtual machine. It installed straight directly on my Ubuntu machine. I tried to run the command. `nft` is not installed though. Should I install it?

Comment: `nft` would be in a package named `nftables`, but if you don't have it already installed, you probably won't need it. When you ran `nmap -sU -p 1194 localhost`, you tested for OpenVPN server in IP address 127.0.0.1. If OpenVPN is listening only on your real outgoing network interface, then that `nmap` command would not be expected to find it. Try `sudo lsof -i udp:1194`; if `lsof` is not installed, install it first. Since a modern version of OpenVPN is IPv6-aware, your `netstat -tulpn` line for OpenVPN will look somewhat different from the example in the article.

Comment: So, I can confirm `lsof` is indeed installed. After running `sudo lsof -i udp:1194`, I get no output.

Comment: You didn't show us the output of any of these commands nor provide IP addresses of the host in question / where you are trying to connect from. Based on your description of events this isn't happening. We have no basis for determining otherwise.

Comment: IP address of the host: 192.168.0.14
I'm trying to connect from a cellphone over LTE. For which command do you like to see the output? For the record, I'm able to successfully connect to my VPN. But I'm trying to understand why I'm able to because I don't see an "allow" rule in my `iptables` config.

Answer (score 1):

From your question, it looks like you are running OpenVPN Access server.

Firstly, the parent process for openvpnas is python

[image]

Secondly, OpenVPN does not listen on loopback address (127.0.0.1) for client connections. And it will make no sense if it will listen on loopback address. Therefore nmap against localhost will always show UDP port 1194 as closed.

Thirdly, OpenVPN Access Server manages iptables on your behalf. You do not have to configure any iptables as compared to OpenVPN Community version.